# how do i remove duplicate records between records

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB like

```
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.13", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.13", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.14", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.14", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.16", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.16", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.16", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.13", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
```

and this is how the query should look

```
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.13", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.14", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.16", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
{"currency_type":"alchemy", "currency_value": "0.13", "created_on": "1605975144322"}
```

I have tried something like that, but it removes all entries with the same value. I only want to remove the entries that are duplicated in the row.

```
DB.objects.aggregate([
            {"$match": {"currency_type": "alchemy"}},     
            {"$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "currency_value": "$currency_value"                
                },
                "created_on": {"$first": "$created_on"},
                "data": {"$first": "$$ROOT"},
                "count": {"$sum": 1}                 
            }},
            {"$sort":{ "created_on" : 1 }}
        ])
```

Any ideas in which direction i can go?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can get max or min of the _id to either keep or remove:

```
DB.objects.aggregate([
            {"$match": {"currency_type": "alchemy"}},     
            {"$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "currency_value": "$currency_value"                
                },
                "created_on": {"$first": "$created_on"},
                "data": {"$first": "$$ROOT"},
                "count": {"$sum": 1},
                "maxId": {$max:"$_id"}
            }},
            {"$sort":{ "created_on" : 1 }}
        ])
```